# Any good software for value investment?

Tags: investing

Is there any good software that helps you analyze a company's performance by digging through their financial statments? I'd like to see a software can automatically collect and parse companies' financial statements periodically and make comparisons based on their price per share or earning per share, etc. Prefably giving investment suggestions or predictions.

Comment: You're talking about the Bloomberg Terminal (or competitor's Reuters terminal)? Its way out of reach for an individual middle-class investor.

Comment: Paying for Bloomberg Terminal is a waste of money, around 1.2k-2k/month. Because they provide loads of information for the price, and the major part of it you aren't going to use anyways unless your field of work is in finance in bank or brokerage firm or something like that. Reuters station is much cheaper. But call up sales and enquire about the prices. You wouldn't use live data, which is costly, so they may come up with cheaper options.

Comment: I am hoping to get an opensource software to do that. If there aren't any, I might write one my own. I am a programmer and have knowledge in data mining and artificial intelligence.

Comment: You might take a look at [WorldCap](http://worldcap.org). They offer a iPad based solution which provides many financial metrics used by value investors.

Comment: Ever look into stock screening software?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope people don’t see this as being facetious but invest some time in learning to do that with Excel. Most financial information websites (Yahoo, MSN, etc.) will allow you to extract all the data you need into excel. This way you can learn to do analysis with something that isn’t a "black box" (as to mean you don’t know the exact equations behind the outputs) whereas with excel you can delve into and really understand the equations behind the numbers you are looking at.

If you use Bloomberg it does all that for you but if you are just starting out you may not truly understand what it means and how everything is connected. If you create the same with excel you have no choice but to deeply understand because you built it from scratch!

I'm certian there are plenty of tutorials to help you out there as every analyst who has worked in finance since the advent of excel has had to create these at one time or another.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As @littleadv and @DumbCoder point out in their comments above, Bloomberg Terminal is expensive for individual investors.

If you are looking for a free solution I would recommend [Yahoo](http://finance.yahoo.com) and [Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance). On the other side, if you need more financial metrics regarding historic statements and consensus estimates, you should look at the iPad solution from [Worldcap](http://www.worldcap.org), which is not free, but significantly cheaper then Bloomberg and Reuters.
*Disclosure: I am affiliated with WorldCap.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was looking for a software that would give me easy access to historical financial statements of a company, preferably in a chart. So that I could easily compare earnings per share or other data between competitors.

Have a look at [Stockdance](http://stockdance.biz) this might be what you are looking for.

Reuters Terminal is way out of my league (price and complexity) and Yahoo and Google Finance just don't offer the features I want, especially on financials. Stockdance offers a sort of stock selection check list on which you can define your own criterion’s. Hence it makes no investment suggestions but let's you implement your own investing strategy.